# WebBrowser crash when using dropdown (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, crash, windows-phone, browser

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the WebBrowser control in my WP8 silverlight project. I have a payment page from a bank, but when you click on the dropdown to choose your card expiration date the app crashes without any debug info.

This only happens in the app, when I open the page in IE (tested on WP8 and WP 8.1) the dropdown works fine, it show the full screen item selector.

Do I need to enable something for it to work inside my app?
`ScriptsEnabled` is set to true.

Here's a video of the crash (happens at the 7 seconds mark).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE_QTfJXaKU&feature=youtube_gdata

edit:
I do however get this error code in the debug console (which I have researched and found nothing useful to xis this issue):

> The program '[2420] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819
>   (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Isolate the problem by creating a blank webpage with just a dropdown in it.  Does it still crash according to your methods?  If no, then there's a lot more going on than just the dropdown.

Comment: It works fine with others, it's just the bank's page that's not working in the WebBrowser control. I have no control over that page since it comes directly from the bank. But the problem must be with WebBrowser control, because the IE app displays the page just fine. I don't get any error code or debugging errors. It just closes with triggering an event.

Comment: I do however get this error code in the debug console (which I have researched and found nothing useful to xis this issue): The program '[2420] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.